# Find element using if else or try except in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, try-catch, findelement

I am confused which is the best and correct way to check if element exists or not? Using `try-except` or `if-else`? What would be the difference and what are advantages/disadvantages of both when trying to find element?

```
def find_logo():
    return driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".navbar-brand [src='/logo/logo.svg']")

if find_logo(): 
    print("Found the logo")
else:
    print("Cannot find the logo")
```

So will get the same result with try except:

```
def find_logo():
    return driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".navbar-brand [src='/logo/logo.svg']")

try:
    find_logo()
    print("Found the logo")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Cannot find the logo")
```

Both seem to work the same way but which is the correct way to do it?

Comment: The question itself is incorrect as in first case `find_logo` returns `list` and in second - single WebElement. So its not about *what approach is correct* but *what output user wants to get*

Comment: Oh yes, the problem is that if it is ```find_element``` and logo image is not there then it will always return error unable to find such element and will not get to the else statement.

Comment: Sooo... Obviously, you need to use `try`/`except` in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canonically both the `if-else` and `try-except` logic needs to be revamped however they needs to be implemented as per your usecase.

---

**if find_logo()**: The `if find_logo()` will be always successful as in `def find_logo()` you have used `find_elements()` which may not return any elements at all. In such case you may require to check if the *list* size is not **0**.

---

**try: find_logo()**: `try: find_logo()` seems to be better organized in comarision to the other with `NoSuchElementException` check in place when the **specific** element isn't found.

---

### Code optimization

However as per best practices, when looking for an element, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following logic:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".navbar-brand [src='/logo/logo.svg']")))
    print("Found the logo")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Cannot find the logo")
```

Note : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation however I have one more question why WebDriverWait for visibility of element better than find_element? Isn't it the same or...?

Comment: @bbfl [Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) these [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) on [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808)

Answer (score -1):

In first case function return a list and in the second case, function return that web element that you are looking for.

Comment: Oh yes, the problem is that if it is ```find_element``` and logo image is not there then it will always return error unable to find such element and will not get to the else statement.